# Repository fragmentation when targetting a project

Tags: git, github, version-control, dvcs

What is relevant when you think about separating a project into several repositories or keeping it in a single repository with separated folders?

In a project with several different parts, those separated repositories would target the following components:

- Data structures
- Core functionality
- Sort of plugins family (one for each)
- Different backends for some components (one for each)

Also considering the option of making a github organisation to store those repositories, because a few of them would be somehow dependant on others. Furthermore, that would help in keeping the personal accout clear.

I've seen all sort of approaches when looking at other projects: from using one big repository to separated small ones. I'm considering going the fragmented way because it's somehow more organised, but it might be an overkill if those parts are not too big.

Answer (score 1):

Use single repository. When it becomes too uncomfortable to work with, split it to multiple smaller repositories.